# Datanode and Nodemanager on slave machine are not able to connect to NameNode and ResourceManager on master machine

Tags: java, apache, sockets, hadoop, tcp

I have installed hadoop on two node cluster-  Node1 and Node2.
Node1 is master and Node2 is slave. Node2's datanode and Nodemanager are not able to connect Namenode and Resourcemanager on Node1 respectively. However  Node1's datanode and Nodemanager are not able to connect Namenode and Resourcemanager on Node1.

---

Node1: jps
18083 ResourceManager 
18572 Jps
18207 NodeManager
17621 DataNode
17827 SecondaryNameNode
17478 NameNode

Node2: jps
1548 DataNode

---

**For Node2 NodeManger is giving below exception:**

*FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from  node2/10.222.188.172 to node1:8031 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost*

**For Node2 DataNode is giving below error:**

*WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: node1/10.222.188.107:9000
2015-06-19 08:42:54,786 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node1/10.222.188.107:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)*

---

**Output of  netstat -nlp | grep 9000 on node1**

*tcp        0      0 10.222.188.107:9000     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17478/java*

**output of netstat -nlp | grep 8031 on node1**:

*tcp        0      0 10.222.188.107:8031     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18083/java*

---

**etc/hosts file node1 & node2:**

127.0.0.1   localhost

10.222.188.106 master

10.222.188.107 node1

10.222.188.172 node2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue.
In iptables rules tcp connection were blocked.
I flushed iptables rules using below command and issue is resolved.

```
sudo iptables -F
```